Blazor Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Navigating to New Page
I get the following error when navigating to a new page from a page with a bound conrol:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The same error also occurs if I update the search text box too quickly. The search function is executed with async IHttpClientFactory currently. If I don't set the list to null it doesn't display the updated results correctly but I believe this is also a problem.
Thoughts?
Razor Page
<SfTextBox Paceholder="Recipe Filter" Width="250px" @oninput="OnChange"></SfTextBox>

<SfListView TValue="clRecipe" DataSource="@recipeFiltered">
    <ListViewEvents TValue="clRecipe" Clicked="Click"></ListViewEvents>
    <ListViewFieldSettings Id="RecipeID" Text="RecipeName" TValue="clRecipe" />
</SfListView>




private async Task OnChange(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    string str = e.Value.ToString();
    recipeFiltered = null;
    recipeFiltered = await RecipeService.getRecipeListNameFilter(str);
}

Update
trying to ensure that the list is never null breaks the control. Currently the control never updates. I dont see how the referenced page solution solves the issue.
recipeFiltered.Add(new clRecipe());
foreach ( clRecipe rep in await RecipeService.getRecipeListNameFilter(str))
{
    recipeFiltered.Add(rep);
}

Updating the page code to remove the control when the list is null seems to be on the right track but still errors randomly and when changing pages.
@if (recipeFiltered is not null)
{
    <SfListView TValue="clRecipe" DataSource="@recipeFiltered">
        <ListViewEvents TValue="clRecipe" Clicked="Click"></ListViewEvents>
        <ListViewFieldSettings Id="RecipeID" Text="RecipeName" TValue="clRecipe" />
    </SfListView>
}


I  had a function which I thought was un-used in my class to generate hash. This was being called which some of the field were null causing an error. Hopfully this helps someone else!
